# Do we also have to transmit the salt with the ciphertext, in addition to the IV for authenticated point to point messaging?

Tags: salt

Imagine a scenario whereby Alice and Bob have a symmetrical messaging system for talking with each other. It's effectively two polystyrene cups joined by a piece of string. Crucially, there is no central server, and nobody logs into nothing. They do though both have the same messaging application. Also imagine that their architecture transmits an IV, cipher text and HMAC as three separate parts of an Encrypt-then-MAC approach.

A shared password is initially required, from which a key is derived, by which the messages can be authenticated. And key derivation functions (à la Argon) require a salt. So does the salt also have to be transmitted along with the other parts?  Otherwise Alice and Bob have to exchange a high entropy salt and the secret password out of band.  Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A salt just needs to be unique to avoid attacks, e.g. attacks using rainbow tables. It may be public, so in that sense it is fine to send it with messages or during some kind of handshake protocol. If multiple messages need to be encrypted then a handshake with a salt makes most sense. That way it would at least not have to be transmitted out of band. The good thing of large random salts is mainly that you don't need to keep any state.

A salt doesn't need to be randomly generated. However, normally you would want to change the salt for each session. If there already is some kind of session identifier then that can be used as salt, possibly together with the ID's of the sender and receiver included (generally you'd use different keys for sender and receiver, even if the keys are symmetric).

If you would allow asymmetric primitives then there are of course options such as Diffie-Hellman key agreement, where the derived key is just used for authentication. It might be a good idea to use some kind of double ratchet or similar where the key depends both on key agreement *and* a password derived key. That way a bad password would not directly influence the security of the key, unless DH gets broken. There are also more efficient PAKE protocols such as SRP available if you'd allow asymmetric primitives.

Notes:

- If you can agree on a secret, high entropy salt then you might as well agree on a symmetric master key and skip the password based derivation altogether.
- Beware that you do need a separate IV if you want to encrypt multiple messages with the same key. If CBC is used then the IV needs to be unpredictable (randomized).
- Usually you'd derive 4 keys a la TLS. One for encryption, one for MAC but for sending messages in both directions. That way it is impossible to replay messages to the sender - without that being detected anyway. You'd first derive a master session key, and derive the other session keys from that using HKDF or a similar KBKDF.

Comment: Thanks, but re. first bullet point. Agreement on a crypto key (say 256 bits) would require it to be written down :-(  Asymmetry isn't possible with my cup & string app.

Comment: I agree; that was more a point to indicate that the secret salt wasn't really an option rather than propose to use a shared key. And if you take authentication and protection against MitM attacks into account then the problem just gets harder.